# I Wanted to do nesting of three tables in a single json and pass that json to HTML so we can display tables?

Tags: python, json, dataframe

I have three tables 
1.table_A
2.table_B
3.table_c
I want to create a json of this three table and call this json in the flask app.
Currently what I am trying is I converted this three tables into JSON using
     pandas.to_json 
like

```
table_1 = pandas.to_json(table_A)
table_2 = pandas.to_json(table_B)   
table_3 = pandas.to_json(table_C)
```

After this I did something like this

```
X = {
"table_1":table_1,
"table_2":table_2,
"table_3":table_3
}
```

and after this I did is
    json_data = json.dumps(X)
and I am saving this as a value in a particular table named JSON_table
is it a right way or any other way to do this in a proper way and more cleaner way.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this ?

```
tables = [table_A, table_B, table_C, table_D]

X = {'table_' + str(number): pandas.to_json(table) for number, table in enumerate(tables)}

json_data = json.dumps(X)
```